# How to redirect HTTPS://example.com to www.example.com==

Tags: redirect, iis-7

I'm trying to redirect a example.com to [www.example.com](http://www.example.com)

All the examples ([here](https://stackoverflow.blog/2008/06/14/dropping-the-www-prefix/) and [here](https://aboutssl.org/iis-redirection-http-to-https/)) I've found work with HTTP://  but **not** with HTTP**S**://

1. http**s**://example.com   DOES NOT redirect
2. http://example.com  does redirect.

   ```
       <rule name="Add WWW prefix" >
       <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="true" />
       <conditions >
      <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^bungalowsoftware.com" />


      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.bungalowsoftware.com/{R:1}"
      redirectType="Permanent" />
   ```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules Let FRT reveal what happens under the hood.

Comment: The rule works fine for https on my side.Did you set your IIS binding correctly? By default, you shouldn't set http and https binding side-by-side. Because when you enable "Require SSL". HTTP binding get corrupted by ssl handshake. So please check your have created binding https://bungalowsoftware.com in your IIS and the rule was placed in the root web.config of this https binding.  Besides, please remember to clean browser cache when you try the redirection.